# How to check if video player is launched in appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am using appium to automate my mobile app. This app has a video player.
I am able to click on Play button but I need to verify that the player is launched successfully.

I am unable to get any resource ID or xpath for the player. Is there any way to verify that player is launched successfully.

Below is the code:

```
    WebElement usernameTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.xyz:id/username"));
    WebElement passwordTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.xyz:id/password"));
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.xyz:id/login_button"));

    usernameTextBox.sendKeys("username");
    passwordTextBox.sendKeys("password");
    driver.hideKeyboard();
    loginButton.click();

    WebElement oneOffEpisode = driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.xyz:id/static_item_title"));
    oneOffEpisode.click();

    WebElement playButton = driver.findElement(By.id("com.abc.xyz:id/episode_portrait_play_button"));
    playButton.click();

    // what should I write here to assert that player is launched successfully?
    assertEquals("", "");
```

Comment: When you can click on the play button that means player has been launched successfully.

Comment: We can just assume this. Is there any way to assert this?

Comment: you are not assuming anything. Play button is on player and if you see play button that means player is there simple.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear earlier but the play button I am clicking is separate from Player. It is on different page. Basically there is a page with list of several videos, each having a play button. When I click on play button on any of these videos, then the player launches and plays the video.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to take screenshots, I would suggest you to use visual automation lib like Sikuli.

Check for the play and pause button at intervals, if the buttons are present and change on tap then you can safely say that the video is playing. Taking screenshots for visual comparison is also a good way of asserting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Timer is one option - Check if the timer loads and its greater than 0:00.
Second option is to check for sound. If sound is being played, it means that video is loaded. Use `dumpsys` command to check sound status.